# Dynamically render controller

Tags: vue.js

I have a template:

```
<template id="chat-template">
    <div class="row hidden-xs-up" id="messages">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">{{ player.username }}</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-cog settings"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus minimize"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-close end"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                <!-- MESSAGES -->
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="button" v-bind:target_id="{{ player.target_id }}"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</template>
```

Component declaration:

```
var chatWindow = Vue.extend({
    props: ['player'],
    template: '#chat-template'
});
```

Inside a method:

```
this.$http.post(url, data, this.options).then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.status == 200) {

                } else if (response.data.status == 600){

                }

            }, function(response) {
                //handling request errors
                console.log('Error: ' + response.data.status);
            });
```

I'm building messaging system and I need to dynamically render new component that displays chat window and add it's instance to specific class in my main HTML. How can I append this new when I got response from backend?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the component from the beginning, and just use `v-if` to render it when your messages load.  Something like:

```
<chat-window v-if="messagesLoaded"></chat-window>

if(response.data.status == 200) {
    this.messages = response.data;
    this.messagesLoaded = true;    
}
```

The idea behind Vue is that you never manually render/append anything to the DOM, you just create the layout and let the javascript values drive the changing DOM.  `v-if` will not render unless the value is true, so it won't build the component until it's needed.

If you need multiple conversations, just do

```
<template v-for="conversation in conversations">
    <chat-window :messages="conversation.messages">
    </chat-window>
</template>
```

Which would create a chat window for every conversation

Comment: That's not what I need. I need to render Chat box when message comes or i click on new message button.

Comment: using `v-if` does not render the component until the expression is true.  So it will not exist until `messagesLoaded` is true. @nix9

Comment: I know but it will render just one chat window. I need few of them depends of conversation number I have opened.